# Install other applications in a WP7 application Programatically

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

**What the WP7 application needs to do?**
  - download some others applications and install them automatically on the device.
    The device will send first a request to a web server with some rules and will receive an answer containing the links to the applications that need
to be downloaded and installed on the device.

As far as I read, the Marketplace is the only way to get apps on a Windows Phone 7 device, so let's suppose that the applications I want to
install are already on the Marketplace and I can refer to each one by their links (according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967553%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) post).

1. Can I **download programmatically** an application from the MarketPlace (having the link to it) in another application and install it
   on the device?
   I do not want to open the app link in browser because this opens the Marketplace hub and points me to the application location.
2. Just for my curiosity: every time you want to install an application from Marketplace you need to sign in with a Windows Live ID?

Thanks & Regards,
Paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You cannot dynamically download or execute code or install applications on WP7. The closest you can get is launching a [`MarketplaceDetailTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.marketplacedetailtask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) which directs the user to a page on the marketplace where they can *choose* to download the application.
2. The user's Live ID remains signed in until they sign out from Settings so, no, they don't have to sign in more than once.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I have another curiosity: If I want to deploy a XAP file to a device using "Application Deployment" tool it is obligatorily to be a registered/unlocked device?
If I'm buying my own device with Wp7 OS on it, I need to pay that annual membership fee of $99 to be able to test on it?

Comment: Annual membership is required to test your application on the phone or submit an application to the marketplace. The [ChevronWP7 team](http://www.chevronwp7.com/) are supposedly working on a supported $9 unlock for running applications on the phone, but a full membership is still required to submit it to the marketlace.

Comment: I have another question:
If I am using the `MarketplaceDetailTask` launcher can I somehow determine in the application that launched this when the user return to the application page - something like a `Completed` event that for example `PhotoChooserTask` has ?

Comment: @Paul - MarketplaceDetailTask has no such event. However, the page's OnNavigatedTo method will be called when the user hits back, so you could always set a flag before you launch the task and check for that flag in the OnNavigatedTo method (or associated event if you're using MVVM).